# Downcasting generic maths types

Tags: c#, .net, generics, .net-6.0

Assuming that I have a generic class/method with a generic number constraint (using the new [preview generic math feature](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/preview-features-in-net-6-generic-math/)):

```
public void DoAThing<TValue>(TValue value) where TValue : struct, INumber<TValue>
{
   ...
}
```

Is there a way to downcast this further to one of the other interfaces?  For example, one of these sorts of things:

```
    if (typeof(IFloatingPoint<TValue>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TValue)))
    {
        // do some floating-point-only logic without a specific value
    }
    if (value is IFloatingPoint<TValue> fpnum)
    {
        // do some floating-point-only logic on fpnum
    }
```

Currently, the compiler objects to this, saying that `TValue` must be convertible to `IFloatingPoint<TValue>` to use it as a parameter... which is exactly what I'm trying to test.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a way to do what you want. Even casting as object first doesn't help. Given that this feature is still experimental, I imagine that this is something that they still need to work out.

Comment: Note that I tested in .NET 6 and v6.0.2 of the System.Runtime.Experimental NuGet package. Not sure whether there may be better support in the .NET 7 preview.